# Hero-section does not scroll on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

This is my site (https://www.subhra.digitalmelodic.in/), the hero section does not scroll on mobile devices.[this section ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8DpK.png) .
I am unable to find the reason. I change z-index but still does not work. I am expecting to resolve this problem.

I am expecting to resolve this problem.

Comment: Well your carousel is capturing touch events preventing scrolling.  Maybe turn off touch for this conrol.

Comment: is working now ?

Comment: @ullaskunder  No, to see what the OP is talking about, put your browser into developer mode, and emulate a mobile device.  Now try and scroll the window up, (NOT with the mouse wheel), but by dragging as if on a mobile.  It won't scroll, because his carousel is capturing the touch events preventing the default behaviour of scrolling.   If you mouseWheel past the carousel you will see dragging works as expected.

Comment: @Keith how can I turn off the touch control?

Comment: https://www.veed.io/view/87db947c-81ec-491a-b24f-a68e834d51bb?panel=share

@Keith

Comment: @ullaskunder  What?

Comment: @SubhraRoy  Looks like your using owl.carousel.js, looking at the Docs, you have an option called -> touchDrag.  As default this is set to true, set this to false. -> https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Comment: Please include your code in the question, as a [mcve]. Don't just tell people to fix your website. Your site may go down, or change, and that makes the question and any answers useless for others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

set touchDrag to false in owl.carousel.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).